# Timed Subscription Schedule in SSRS sends out duplicate emails

Tags: sql-server, iis, reporting-services, smtp

I have created a one-time subscription in SSRS report manager 2008. However I keep getting duplicate emails sent out by the subscription. The interval between each email is about 30 minutes.

I have checked SQL agent job and it looks the SQL agent job is created correctly. It just runs once and after that the next run time is cleared.

I also checked SMTP service on local machine by testing code. SMTP works fine for test email without duplicate. So I guess probably it is something wrong in SSRS. Any advice on where I can look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update on this problem.

When I enable the reporting service log, the problem never happens again.

To the configuration file, the following is added.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultTraceSwitch" value="3" />
    </switches>   </system.diagnostics>



<RStrace>
                  <add name="FileName" value="ReportServerService_" />
                  <add name="FileSizeLimitMb" value="32" />
                  <add name="KeepFilesForDays" value="5" />
                  <add name="Prefix" value="tid, time" />
                  <add name="TraceListeners" value="debugwindow, file" />
                  <add name="TraceFileMode" value="unique" />
                  <add name="HttpTraceFileName" value="ReportServerService_HTTP_" />
                  <add name="HttpTraceSwitches" value="date,time, clientip,username,serverip,serverport,host,method,uristem,uriquery,protocolstatus,bytesreceived,timetaken,protocolversion,useragent,cookiereceived,cookiesent,referrer" />
                  <add name="Components" value="all:3,http:4" />
  </RStrace>
```

However we are not sure if the problem is gone as well if we remove the configuration section. We don't want to keep the log as it grows quite fast.

Comment: you might report this on connect.microsoft.com or post in the msdn forums - it seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to make sure that an extra job was not created.  Maybe poke around the report server database and see if there is some kind of spare schedule records - but it's hard to understand how it wouldn't show up in the UI.

Have you deleted the subscription and recreated it?

Comment: Only one job is created. 

I created new subscription to test. Do you think existing subscriptions should be removed first?